# File[] limit on amount of files to add?

Tags: android, android-file

Do anyone know if there is an an limit on the File function in regards to creating File[]
Im trying to put all files in an folder (roughly 3000files) into an File[].

But it only displays 100 when i inspect the File[] in breakpoint.

Is there a way to set this higher?

```
    public ArrayList<Signs> getArrayOfSignsFromFolder(String imagePath, String videoPath2, String illustrativePath) {

    ArrayList<Signs> arrayOfSigns = new ArrayList<Signs>();
    Signs sign;
    File directoryPhoto = new File(imagePath);
    File[] photoListing = directoryPhoto.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            if (name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg")) {
                return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg");
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    File directoryVideo = new File(videoPath2);
    File[] videoListing = directoryVideo.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            if (name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp4")) {
                return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp4");
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    File directoryIllu = new File(illustrativePath);
    File[] illuListing = directoryIllu.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {



        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            if (name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg")) {
                return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg");
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    if (illuListing != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < illuListing.length; i++) {
            String illupath = illuListing[i].toString();
            String illuName = illuListing[i].getName();
            int removeIlluExtension = illuName.lastIndexOf(".");
            if (removeIlluExtension > 0) {
                illuName = illuName.substring(0, removeIlluExtension);
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < photoListing.length; j++) {
                String photoPath = photoListing[j].toString();
                String photoName = photoListing[j].getName();
                int removePhotoExtension = photoName.lastIndexOf(".");
                if (removePhotoExtension > 0) {
                    photoName = photoName.substring(0, removePhotoExtension);
                }
                if (illuName.equals(photoName)) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < videoListing.length; k++) {
                        String videoPath = videoListing[k].toString();
                        String videoName = videoListing[k].getName();
                        int removeVideoExtension = videoName.lastIndexOf(".");
                        if (removeVideoExtension > 0) {
                            videoName = videoName.substring(0, removeVideoExtension);
                        }
                        if (videoName.equals(photoName)) {
                            sign = new Signs(videoName, photoPath, videoPath, illupath);
                            arrayOfSigns.add(sign);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return arrayOfSigns;

}}
```

illuList folder contains: 3086 files
photoList folder contains: 1366 files
videoList folder contains: 386 files.

This function should return 386 items (the filename in each folder is respectfully named the same for matching, and all video files have matching photofiles and illufiles);

i barely scratch the a***** filenames on my listView. returning a total of 28 items

Comment: 3000 is nothing. It is unclear what you inspect. You should inspect File[] files.size(). (or files.length or something like that).

Comment: `Im trying to put all files in an folder (roughly 3000files) into an File[].`. Better show your code.

Comment: Just a guess, but are you recursively putting files into that array that are contained in folders? That might explain why you dont see as many as you expect

Comment: when i inspect .lenght i get the correct value of 3xxx files. but when i inspect the File[] it only displays 100, and it only inputs 100 to the arraylist after. (have a for loop through three folders and match names to insert in arraylist) and then add the connected ones to an arraylist.It should return roughly 350 items to the arraylist, but my listview only displays 28 items.

Comment: Will add the function code

Comment: `but when i inspect the File[] it only displays 100`. Very unclear what you are doing. Moreover you cannot inspect File[]. You can inspect photoListing or videoListing. So please be clear. Where ar you talking about?

Comment: When i display any of those created File[]´s each only display 100 "files" in them. when i check length for each they display the correct ones. But im only getting 28 matching elements in the arraylist. Which sounds correct if it only compares 100 files from each. 100 files down the list on illuListing (that contains 3xxx) means there isnt gonna be many matches towards the other given the amount of files compared to the other. Sry for bad explanation:)

Comment: `function should return 386 items`. You forgot to explain how your function works. And why it should return 386. And what is exactly your problem? Does the function deliver wrong results or do you not know how to use the debugger?

Comment: `When i display any of those created File[]´s each only display 100 "files" in them`. Sorry but i really don't understand what you aredoing here. Display in what? In a listview? And you are stil talking about File[] instead naming a variable.

Comment: It should return 386 items, because for each xx.mp4 in folder video, theres an matching xx.jpg in folder photo, which there again has an matching xx.jpg in folder illustration. The function should first take the biggest folder, get the first element in file[0], take the filename(without extension), loop through the second largest folder and compare each of the element of that file[], when it matches, it goes furter in and looks through the smallest folder to find matching name again, when finished it will return different paths, for matching filenames (minus extension).

Comment: At the end it should take each of those paths (string), create an "object" and put that object in the arraylist. I then later have an ListView that loads from that arraylist. problem is that the arraylist ends up at containing 28 objects (filename not passed ab****.xx). When it should have 386 objects

Comment: When i display any of those created File[]´s each only display 100 "files" in them. Sorry bad put. I meant when i inspect any of the File[] arrays during breakpoints in debugging, they only show 100 files each when i expand it in debugger.